# Passing a single scalar from numpy array in OpenMDAO 1.x

Tags: openmdao

I have an independent variable x which is vector treated as a numpy array.  I'd like to be able to constrain some of the values in that vector based on other values in the vector.  i.e. x_(k) < x_(k+1).  I've tried:

```
root.add('p1',IndepVarComp('x',x=np.ones(10,dtype=float))
root.add('con',ExecComp('c0=x[1]-x[0]')
root.connect('p1.x','con.x')
```

That gives me errors about variable not existing and arrays trying to be connected to floats.  What is the correct syntax to connect a particular value from an output array to a scaler input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of missing parenthesis in the code you typed, but those must come from transcribing it to here. The main thing you were missing was an extra argument to `ExecComp` so that it knows how to size the incoming x.

```
import numpy as np

from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, IndepVarComp, ExecComp

prob = Problem()
prob.root = root = Group()

root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', np.array([3, 7, 5], dtype=float)))
root.add('con', ExecComp('co = x[1] - x[0]', x=np.zeros(3, )))
root.connect('p1.x','con.x')

prob.setup()
prob.run()
print('con', prob['con.co'])
```

When I run this, I get the expected output:

```
##############################################
Setup: Checking root problem for potential issues...

No recorders have been specified, so no data will be saved.

Setup: Check of root problem complete.
##############################################

('con', 4.0)
```

An alternate way to do this is to use a scaler expression and then issue connections from a single index of 'p1.x':

```
root.add('con2', ExecComp('co = b - a'))
root.connect('p1.x', 'con2.a', src_indices=[0])
root.connect('p1.x', 'con2.b', src_indices=[1])
```